# Show random emoji inside a Label in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to have a random emoji inside a Label and every tableViewCell should show a different, random picked emoji...
I tried following function, but sadly it's giving me following error: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'shuffled'

```
let emojis: [String] = {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "emojis", withExtension: "txt")!
    let list = try! String(contentsOf: url).map { String($0) }
    return list.shuffled()
}()
```

Comment: shuffled is only available as a native API in Swift 4.2. Otherwise you need to define your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use this `extension` for emoji string :)

```
extension NSObject {

    public var emojiString: String {
        let pointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        // You can adjust your range
        //let range = 0x1F600...0x1F64F
        let range = 0x1F300...0x1F3F0
        let index = (pointer.hashValue % range.count)
        let ord = range.lowerBound + index
        guard let scalar = UnicodeScalar(ord) else { return "❓" }
        return String(scalar)
    }

}
```

Just call `cell.textLabel?.text = cell.emojiString` and you're good to go.

Comment: Wow, perfect, thanks a lot :-) worked instantly fine

Comment: Using the hash of the cell object seems a little screwy. That means the emoji will track the cell, even if the cell gets recycled the emoji will show up at a different indexPath.

Comment: This extension will pollute all NSObjects. Plus it forces the range of emojis to be used. Whereas the text file may contain emojis with non-contiguous unicode codes. And finally, there is the slight possibility of generating the same emoji more than once in the tableView. the `scrambled()` proposed by @DuncanC is the right answer. All the asker has to do is return `list.scrambled()`

Comment: When you say "you can adjust your range," how do you know what the upper and lower bound should be?  What range would include all emoji on iOS 13.2, for example?

Answer (score 8):

```
po String(UnicodeScalar(Array(0x1F300...0x1F3F0).randomElement()!)!)
```

Comment: please add context so all understand why this answer would be the best compared to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007723/8928024.

Answer (score 4):

As Carpsen says, the shuffled() function is only in Swift ≤ 4.2. In earlier versions of the language you have to write your own.

Here is an example implementation. I called my `scrambled()`, so it will work in any version of Swift including 4.2:

```
extension Array {
    func scrambled () -> [Element] {
        var source = self
        var dest = Array<Element>()
        for _ in 1...self.count {
            let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(source.count)))
            dest.append(source.remove(at: index))
        }
        return dest
    }
}
```

You could scramble the entire set of emojis, but it seems to me you'd be better off creating an array of random emoji when you first populate the data source of your table view. To do that you could use a function `randomEmoji()`:

```
func randomEmoji() -> String {
    let range = 0x1F300...0x1F3F0
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.count)))
    let ord = range.lowerBound + index
    guard let scalar = UnicodeScalar(ord) else { return "❓" }
    return String(scalar)
}
```

So you'd create a stuct to hold all the data for a table view cell, and then populate each struct with a call to `randomEmoji()`.

Note that the `randomEmoji()` function only chooses emoji in the unicode range from 0x1F300 to 0x1F3F0. Also, the approach of using `randomEmoji()` may cause duplicate emoji.

Comment: The `scrambled()` may be an extension to `Sequence`. In Swift 4.2, the shuffling algorithm is given here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c66e136c18fc4146c7ef3eb52f5e534245b34a1c/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift . As to `randomEmoji()` there is always the small probability of generating the same emoji twice.

Comment: That's true, duplicate emoji are possible. You have to create an array of random indexes and remove one at a time if you want to avoid that.

Comment: What is the proof that all emoji exist contiguously within the range 0x1F300...0x1F3F0 ?

Comment: @NerdyBunz I don't have any proof that all emoji exist within a given range. In fact I suspect that they don't. I was just providing an alternative method, based on KoingDev's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using Swift 4.2, the `shuffled()`is not available and the error message is spot on.

You could create your own `shuffled()` function.